# PHP: How to group arrays by their keys?

Tags: php

I have an `uploads` array that looks like this:

```
$uploads[0] = array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'blah');
$uploads[1] = array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'blah');
$uploads[2] = array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'blah');
$uploads[3] = array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'foobar');
```

I want to create this array:

```
$upload_fields = array(
   'blah' => array(
               array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'blah')
               array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'blah')
               array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'blah')
    ),
   'foobar' => array(
               array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'foobar')    
    )
);
```

Basically I want to group the arrays based on their labels. The arrays to be grouped are dynamic otherwise I could do something like:

```
$array_group_1 = array();
$array_group_2 = array();

foreach($uploads as $upload) {
    if($upload['label'] == 'blah') {
        array_push($array_group_1, $upload);
    }  else {
        array_push($array_group_2, $upload);        
    }
}

$upload_fields = array(
    'blah' => $array_group_1,
    'foobar' => $array_group_2
);
```

But since the keys are dynamic how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
$uploads[0] = array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'blah');
$uploads[1] = array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'blah');
$uploads[2] = array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'blah');
$uploads[3] = array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'foobar');

foreach($uploads as $u){
    $upload_fields[$u['label']][] = $u;
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($upload_fields),'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are alot of exotic array functions you can use to get dynamic array keys and values http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

The following code can be optimized by condensing that `if else` statement, but I left it like this to make the example very clear

```
$uploads[0] = array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'blah');
$uploads[1] = array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'blah');
$uploads[2] = array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'blah');
$uploads[3] = array('type' => 'upload', 'label' => 'foobar');

$result = array();

foreach($uploads AS $upload)
{
    if(array_key_exists($upload['label'], $result))
    {
        array_push($result[$upload['label']], $upload);
    }
    else
    {
        $result[$upload['label']] = array();
        array_push($result[$upload['label']], $upload);
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = array();
$final_array = array();

foreach($uploads as $upload){
    if(!in_array($upload['label'], $temp)){
        $final_array[$upload['label']] = array('type' => upload['type'], 'label' => $temp);
        $temp[] = $upload['label'];
    }
}

var_dump($final_array);
```